# Post request body incorrectly parsed

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, http-post

i'm trying to make a $http.post like this:

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: '//192.168.2.1:3000/auth/signup',
   data: $scope.credentials,
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   }
})
```

when:

```
$scope.credentials = {email: 'some_email', password: 'some_password'}
```

and in Node, I'm logging:
console.log(req.body)

and I get:

```
{ '{"email":"some_email","password":"some_password"}': '' }
```

i don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Have you tried to set content type to `application/json`?

Comment: you're assuming angular is automatically serializing form data for you.Imagine the content type was text/xml,you'll have to actually send a string,not a JSON object.So send actually form data string `data:"foo=bar&bar=baz..."`

Comment: @mpm AngularJS **is** automatically serializing data (see [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#transforming-requests-and-responses))!

Comment: @Blackhole to json,maybe,not to xml or form data.It doesnt serialize js objects to form data.

Comment: @mpm You're wrong, guy. Have a look [at the code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L105), which makes a simple check on the data itself, not on the headers or something else.

Comment: @Blackhole all you showed me is json serialization.Show me where angular serialize data in XML or form data ? it doesnt that's why the OP has the problem he has.He's trying to send form encoded datas,not a json string.Now i'm not saying what the OP is trying to do makes sense,just that Angular,given an object `{foo:"bar",bar:"baz"}` wont transform it into `foo=bar&bar=baz` automatically

Comment: @mpm Oh, OK. Mutual incomprehension, sorry ^^. Let's summarize: AngularJS serializes data in a JSON string, not in a form-encoded one.

Comment: @mpm, you are right. Please place your comment as an answer so i can accept it, upvote it and close this question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming angularjs is automatically serializing form data for you.

You need to serialize your form data yourself when dealing with content types that are not json.

For instance, when the Content-Type equals `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` , given an object `{foo:"bar",bar:"baz"}` , it needs to be serialized as `foo=bar&bar=baz`